# Delete existing Image from database using JavaScript and asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

The code below View and deletes the images only from Client-Side I want to delete it from the database also,

Razor View :

```
                 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LatesAd)
                        {
                            <div class="img-wrap">
                                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <img src="~/upload/@item.ImgPath" >
                            </div>
                        }


                    <script>
                   
                    var closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.img-wrap .close')
                    for (var i = 0, l = closeBtns.length; i < l; i++)
                    {
                        closeBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                            var imgWrap = this.parentElement;
                            imgWrap.parentElement.removeChild(imgWrap);
                        });
                    }
                </script>
```

Controller :

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
       {
        ViewBag.LatesAd = (from f in _context.AdsImg
                           where f.AdId == id
                           select f).ToList();
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do so, you need to communicate to the backend that you are deleting the image.

For example, when the user clicks `.close` besides just removing HTML from the page you can send AJAX request to the server with image ID or smth.

On the backend you should have `Destroy` or somethings similar method.